# URL Rewrite and absolute/relative urls

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I set

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^myusers/([0-9]+)$    user.php?user_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

it works, btu oviously every link in my site will be reditct to

```
mydomain.com/myusers/index.php  [not existing]
```

instead of

```
mydomain.com/index.php
```

there is a simpler option to do the rewrite without having to recode each link in mywebsite?

thanks

Comment: It's difficult to see what you actually want to do.  YOu didn't specify, but if that rewrite rule is working you must have put it in an .htaccess file, correct?  Please edit your question and give a clear example of what you expect to receive and what you want the result to be, and what you mean by 'recode each link'.  Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

> there is a simpler option to do the rewrite without having to recode each link in mywebsite?

If you want to simulate a directory structure like `myusers/125`, not really. To the browser, it looks like a normal directory, and it will make all relative requests accordingly.

You could put together a mod_rewrite workaround (redirecting all requests in `/myusers/125/*` back to the root directory), but that would be a terrible kludge. You could also use [the `<base>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/base).

The best thing to do, though, would be to fix the links on the site!